# Return data from node service to angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I was following the Mean Machine book. One of the examples is to connect to mongo db and retrieve all the users. The book seems a little out dated( Already got 2-3 errors which i fixed).

Issue is that my service does not connect to mongodb and return the data. .From UI, the service returns html for the current page.The table is not being populated.

But when I invoke the service through postman, i get the data

The code for the User retrieval is this.

> User Service:

```
angular.module('userService', [])

.factory('User', function($http) {

    //create new object for factory
    var userFactory = {};

    //get single user
    userFactory.get = function(id) {

        return $http.get('/api/user/' + id);
    };

    //get all users
    userFactory.all = function() {
        return $http.get("/api/user/");
    };
...
```

Shown only the relevant parts above.

> Controller:

```
angular.module('userCtrl', ['userService'])

.controller('userController', function(User) {
    var vm = this;
    //processing control
    vm.processing = true;

    //Grab all users on load
    User.all()
        .then(function(udata) {
            console.log(udata.data);
            vm.processing = false;
            vm.users = udata.data;
        });
})
```

> HTML(all.html)

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in user.users">
            <td>{{person._id}}</td>
            <td>{{person.name}}</td>
            <td>{{person.username}}</td>
            <td class="col-sm-2">
                <a ng-href="/users/{{ person._id }}" class="btn btn-danger">Edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

> Main Angular Files

```
angular.module('userApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'app.routes',
    'authService',
    'mainCtrl',
    'userCtrl',
    'userService'
])

//app config to integrate token to request
.config(function($httpProvider) {

    //attach auth interceptor to http requests
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptor');
})
```

> HTML File(index.html)

```
<body ng-app="userApp" ng-controller="mainController as main">
....
<main class="container">
            <!-- ANGULAR VIEWS -->
            <div ng-view></div>
        </main>
</body>
```

The users table is inserted into the above template.

> Route:

```
angular.module('app.routes', ['ngRoute'])

.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
 //users
    .when('/users', {
        templateUrl: 'app/views/pages/users/all.html',
        controller: 'userController',
        controllerAs: 'user'
    });

});
```

Is the issue due to the version mismatch? Read that the $http service has been upgraded.
Thanks for the help

Comment: I haven't used AngularJS in a while, but don't you need to pass the dependency for your factory function like this..? `['$http', function($http) { ... }]`? Here's the documentation on dependency injection. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: Do you have the ng-app and ng-controller set up?  Could you please post a quick plunker?

Comment: @Srijith The site seems to be blocked by my office firewall..

Comment: That might probably explain this

Comment: @Srijith I am not using any external JS files. All of them are in my local folder as well as the mongodb is running locally. Dont think firewall is the issue.

Comment: Another way you could find help here is to edit the question and post a code snippet. Can you do that?

Comment: Can you post your full html code (especially the part where you have declared the `ng-controller`)? Also, can you tell what fields `udata.data` contain?

Comment: @Chinni;@Srijith : Update the question with more code snippets. Please let me know if you need more snippets. I believe i have put all relevant snippets.

Comment: @ShabinHashim what's the result of `console.log(udata.data);`?

Comment: @ShabinHashim There is some issue with your html code. You have initialised a controller on `<body>` tag and you have your `ng-view` inside that. That doesn't make sense. Remove that `ng-controller` from `<body>`

Comment: Are the HTTP calls being made?

Comment: @Chinni : Removing controller from body has no effect. infact it removes some funcitonality handled by the mainController.
akaphenom : I dont know how to debug angular app. But i put an alert statement within the factory method (userFactory.all () ) and the alert is shown. Is that what u meant?

Comment: Yes. Removing the `mainController` will obviously remove the functionality handled by it. The point is, don't wrap `ng-view` in some other controller and definitely not to the `<body>` tag in this case. `ng-view` should be independent of that.